# MKMapView Not rendring on Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mkmapview

I am trying to use MKMapView but the it won't render the tiles on view.

I am getting this in the debugger.

> "Your Application has attempted to access the Map Kit API. You cannot
>   access this API without an entitlement. You may receive an entitlement
>   from the Mac Developer Program for use by you only with your Mac App
>   Store Apps. For more information about Apple's Mac Developer Program,
>   please visit developer.apple.com."

I have searched for the solution but can't find the proper solution for this. I have enabled the maps services to in the member centre, but still unable to resolve my issue.

Is there anyone who have any idea about this?

P.S: I am using developer Id application certificate, and it doesn't use any provision profile for code signing.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, go to your Application's target and select the Capabilities tab. There you can flip 'Maps' from Off to On. This will add the entitlement.